# This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox, compiling, 22.04

im new to ubuntu and am struggling with the full screen issue. I tried to run `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` and get the message that my system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.

Im using VirtualBox 6.1.34 and ubuntu 22.04 LTS

I read that installing `virtualbox-guest-dkms` can solve the problem but its not available for my Version of Virtualbox.

So how else can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `dkms` first.

Run

```
sudo apt install dkms
```

Then install Guest Additions again.